# How can I keep the cover on my tefillin shel yad from falling off?

Tags: tefilin, how-to

My tefillin shel yad came with a cover on it that I think is for protecting its squareness. The problem is, the cover isn't tight against the bayit, so it ends up falling off. Any simple tips to prevent that?

Comment: Use glue :)   Just kidding, of course. Don't do this!

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Keter-Kisuyad/dp/B00YQDKFMA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a piece of paper and fold it over a few times. Insert it between the *shel yad* and the cover. This will wedge it in place.

Tip: a thick piece of paper, works well and only needs to be folded over once; it naturally pushes against the fold, and wedges itself.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll try it out tomorrow, be"h.

Comment: @Scimonster Did it work?

Comment: Perfect solution. Invisible, and it doesn't interfere with putting it away.

Answer (score 2):

A good solution is [this product](http://tzitzit.tallit-shop.com/kisu-yad-tefillin-protector/). It stays firmly on the bayis of the shel yad, and won't come off awkwardly in the middle of Shacharis when you move the wrong way! ;) Here is a description of the product from the link I provided:

> Rubber tefillin cover protects the Shel Yad from being damaged or worn through contact with clothing, bumping, etc.
>   Designed to protect the tefillin corners, and help maintain their shape and squareness. Stays in place on almost any size tefillin (32-36 mm).
>   According to Rabbi Asher Weiss, the Kisu Yad is a hiddur mitzvah and a worthy innovation. This simple, patented device offers a solution for the issue of "roeh es ha'avir" (see Sanhedrin 89a). Rabbi Mordechai Eliyahu zt"l held that one should remove the plastic cover when reciting the brachah, but upon seeing the Kisu Yad remarked, "You don't even have to remove it when you say Birkat Tefillin."

[Special thanks to Ben's Tallit Shop at [tzitzit.tallit-shop.com](http://www.tallit-shop.com/)]

Comment: Could you explain a little more about the product, and what makes it different from a normal cover?

Comment: @Scimonster - Added a little description from the link I provided.

Comment: Can confirm works amazingly

Answer (score 2):

Putting your sleeve over it (or over part of it) works, in my experience.

Comment: This certainly is a solution. But, it also disposes the necessity of having that square cover on in the first place, no?

Comment: @DanF Not really. The _bayis_ would rub against the fabric of the sleeve and lose its' squareness.

Answer (score 2):

Put a layer or two of scotch tape on the inside of the cover (not the tefillin itself).

This is no different than putting in a slip of paper except that the tape is not likely to fall out when pulling off the cover.

Answer (score 1):

Putting a rubber band around the cover seems to do the trick.

This is not a prefect solution for me though, as now the cover gets stuck in the case when I take my tefillin out. I'm interested in hearing other options as well.

Answer (score -1):

Take off the little square thing during davening.

Comment: Then you run the danger of the bayit bumping into things and rounding out.